# Problems creating correct ddl from entities using eclipselink

Tags: jpa, orm, eclipselink

I have two entities Person & Status with manyToOne relation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @JoinColumn(name = "STATUS_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Status status;

    // setters & getters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STATUS")
public class Status implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "ABBREVIATION")
    private String abbreviation;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "status")
    private Collection<Person> personCollection;

    // setters & getters    
}
```

when I try to automatically generate the db tables from these entities I get the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
`ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`FIRST_NAME` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`LAST_NAME` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`NICK_NAME` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`STATUS_ID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
INDEX `FK_PERSON_STATUS_ID` (`STATUS_ID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_PERSON_STATUS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`STATUS_ID`) REFERENCES `status` (`ID`)
)

CREATE TABLE `status` (
`ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ABBREVIATION` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`PERSONCOLLECTION` LONGBLOB NULL,
`TITLE` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
```

)

Obviously something is wrong because I do not need to have a `PERSONCOLLECTION LONGBLOB` field in my `status` table.
am I doing something wrong with the mapping?

Using: Netbeans 8, Eclipselink, JPA 2.1, mysql 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove @basic annotation also use "List" instead of "Collection"

Comment: removing @basic did the trick. it turns out I should have used `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "status", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` instead or even `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "status")` as OneToMany relations are lazily loaded by default.